# AJAX request in JSF running in GlassFish 4.1

Tags: jsf, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4.1

In the JSF Application there is this problem:

The application contains some elements inside a `t:dataTable` that are `f:ajax` enabled as following:

```xhtml
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <t:dataTable id="someTable" ...>
        ...
        <f:facet name="header">
            <t:commandLink action="#{someBean.someAction()}">
                <t:outputText value="Some command"/>
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="someTable"/>
            </t:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
        ...
    </t:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The "Some command" should do something and refresh the "someTable" only.

Now the problem is: this scenario is WORKING under **GlassFish 3.1.2**, but under **GlassFish 4.1** it is problematic as following:

The "Some command" works perfectly, and updates the someTable without any problem, but no other non-ajax action elements outside the someTable (or inside the Table) works.
They work, but do not show what they do, so that when we refresh the page, the changes appear.

Now, I tried to make the AJAX as following:

```xhtml
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="form"/>
```

And everything seems to be working just fine.

I need to update only the table, not the whole form.

Does anyone have a solution (web.xml config) or some tip?

There is no PrimeFaces/ICEFaces/RichFaces used in this project.

Thanks

**EDIT:** The names are correct (without : as prefixes, or anything else). The exact same scenario works perfectly under GlassFish 3.1.
Do we need to look into some security settings, or other configurations?

**EDIT2:** as @Tiny said in his comment, without `multipart/form-data` it worked, but then we can't make any Upload. The Upload doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You should be facing some version related problems. The default Mojarra version is different under both the server versions. Did you balance it along with other software versions?

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you mean by "balance it", we tried the same exact simple implementation on Glassfish 3.1.2 and it works (it works even without GlassFish at all, just some container), but with the new GlassFish 4.1 it doesn't work, and it does the problem above!

Comment: While I cannot say off the top of my head what Mojarra version GlassFish 3.1.2 contains, GlassFish 4.1 contains Mojarra 2.2.7. Chances might be the version incompatibilities between your code and the shipped Mojarra version in these two different versions of GlassFish server. It is just one of the several possibilities - not a milestone. Describing the problem more accurately by observing  the server log for any errors/exceptions, browser console/HTTP monitor etc could lead you to the solution. (I am not active on ICEFaces and RichFaces. So, I cannot say anything about them, if used at all).

Comment: Using `<f:ajax>` when `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data` looks something wonky, by the way.

Comment: Is this the real code? `render="someTable"` and `render="form"` should never have worked, either. The naming container prefix is missing.

Comment: @Tiny It actually work, and even it is mentioned in the documentations and some books we got it from. Not sure if that is the cause, but removing it didn't change the result.

Comment: @BalusC It actually works on GlassFish 4.1, yes in our sample project it is the same exact name.